# How to do template inheritence with Sinatra and Slim?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

Using Sinatra and Slim, how can I do template inheritance? I can't find an answer on Google and the documentation on Slim is sparse. Let's say I have the following files:

**main.rb**

```
# Sinatra app
get '/login' do
   slim :login
end

get '/display' do
   slim :display
end
```

**layout.slim**

```
html
    body 
        == yield
```

**sub_layout.slim**

```
div[id="parent_div"]
    div[id="child_div"]
       h3 Rendering content
       == yield
       p display.slim should be rendered in == yield

    div[id="child_div"]
       h1 Rendering stuff in sublayout
       p Hello this div should go underneath the above div.
```

**login.slim**

```
p Welcome to the login page
```

**display.slim**

```
p Welcome to the display page
```

By default, Slim will use **layout.slim** as the base, so it will be automatically inherited when rendering the login and display templates.

However, I want **display.slim** to inherit from **sub_layout.slim**, which in turn inherits **layout.slim**. **login.slim** will inherit directly from **layout.slim**, which is the default behavior so this is fine.

How can I do this with Sinatra and Slim?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is an arbitrary call for layout files. Sometimes you want it sometimes you don't. Makes it hard for Sinatra to know what's next.

I'd recommend you use partials:

```
# in your app.rb
helpers do
  def partial(template, locals = {})
    slim template, :layout => false, :locals => locals
  end
end
```

Then you can use a regular layout file and have it called by default. As you do.

In `display.slim` you could then call your sublayout partial:

```
==partial :sub_layout
```

That's it. Works well. You can even use multiple partials or nest them. Whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make `display.slim` be rendered in a specific area in `sub_layout.slim`? I modified my question where `sub_layout.slim` has a `== yield` where all content should go if a tmeplate wants use the sublayout.

Comment: hm, no idea. Don't quite see why you'd want something as complicated as that. But my first guess would be to check out tilt: https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt it's responsible for rendering templates in Sinatra and it looks like you can but dislpay in another block to be renedered.